# .BAT file that starts ASP.NET Development Server, then opens in browser

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I am trying to create a .bat file that starts the ASP.NET Dev Server outside of Visual Studio, and then opens the site in a browser. What I have so far does successfully start the Dev Server, but then it stops there and doesn't open the browser.

Here is what I have in my .bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE" /port:4608 /path:"C:\Projects\a_project\Dev\path-to-site" /vpath:"/path-to-site"
start "http://localhost:4608/path-to-site/sitefinity"
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Based upon some of your answers I added the start /B to the first line and now neither the the web server or the browser open. I just get a new empty cmd prompt window. Here is the latest that is not working:

```
start /B "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE" /port:4608 /path:"C:\Projects\a_project\Dev\path-to-site" /vpath:"/path-to-site"
start "http://localhost:4608/path-to-site/sitefinity"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I figured it out with help from you all and some trial and error. See the final solution below.

Comment: Why do you want this? You could easily write a script that will make your website run on IIS.

Comment: This bat file will go on the desktop of a non-programmer that has Visual Web Developer on their machine but would prefer not to have to use it just to run the site locally..... I know, it seems weird but that's the solution we came up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following was the final working script:

```
start /D "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0" /B WebDev.WebServer.EXE /port:4608 /path:"C:\Projects\a_project\Dev\path-to-site" /vpath:"/path-to-site"
start http://localhost:4608/path-to-site/sitefinity/
```

You'll notice I had to use the /D param to get into the right path (I wanted the user to be able to just run this off of their desktop) and then use /B param to run the given command in the background.

Also, I found that in order to use the start command and just pass it a URL directly to just use the default browser you have to state the URL with no quotes.

You can use the ASP.NET Dev Server for VS 2010 using the following:

```
start /D "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0" /B WebDev.WebServer40.EXE /port:4608 /path:"C:\Projects\a_project\Dev\path-to-site" /vpath:"/path-to-site"
start http://localhost:4608/path-to-site/sitefinity/
```

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server will only be ON until the batch program is running. It will stop after the batch file finishes.

You should use the `START` command with the `/b` switch to keep it running as a background process. Try this:

`start /B webdev.webserver.exe .........`

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work, please see my updated question above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a 'start' at the beginning of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start "" /b WebDev.WebServer.EXE
```

It seems that the first parameter `title` becomes not-optional when a switch parameter is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\
```

with

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\
```